# How can I switch between compilers in the makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11
MCFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11

LDFLAGS= -shared
MLDFLAGS= 

MSOURCES=main.cpp MCC.cpp Point3D.cpp
SOURCES= mainDLL.cpp MCC.cpp Point3D.cpp

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
MOBJECTS=$(MSOURCES:.cpp=.o)

EXECUTABLE=h2r.dll
MEXECUTABLE=h2r

CC=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
CC=g++

all: clean $(MSOURCES) $(MEXECUTABLE)


dll: clean $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)


$(MEXECUTABLE): $(MOBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(MLDFLAGS) $(MOBJECTS) -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean: 
    rm *.o $(MEXECUTABLE) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

How can I initialize the CC with the cross compiler(`CC=i686-w64-mingw32-g++`) when the `make dll` command is emitted and  how can I use the gnu compiler when the `make all` is emitted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set a variable based on what target is being executed you can do something like:

```
all: CC=g++
all: clean $(MSOURCES) $(MEXECUTABLE)

dll: CC=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
dll: clean $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Define two different CC instead of redefining the one. Since you have different rules for the all and dll, you can just use the other compiler in the other rule. Somehow like this:

```
CCDLL=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
CCALL=g++

all: clean $(MSOURCES) $(MEXECUTABLE)


dll: clean $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)


$(MEXECUTABLE): $(MOBJECTS)
    $(CCALL) $(MLDFLAGS) $(MOBJECTS) -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CCDLL) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

Comment: He's using the same rule to compile .cpp-files though. Now you are only changing the compiler used for linking the program.

Comment: Thats true, would make sence to split this too into two separate rules. Maybe make for one rule `.cpp.o` files and for the other `.o` files. Therefore you don't overwrite the other files all the time and therefore don't need to recompile all the files all the time again.

Answer (score 1):

Your overwriting whatever is in the CC variable. Why don't you just have:

```
CC_DLL=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
CC=g++
```

And simply use the relevant one in your targets.